# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Ether") to str

Tags: python, csv, feature-extraction, pcap, tshark

I working in Google Colab.
I have pcap file (Network packet traffic of IoT sensors) and I want to extract the features from these packets and save it as csv file to start train machine learning algorithms.
I install tshark. but I'm still have this problem (TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Ether") to str)
the error in line

```
  tsharkcommand = ("tshark -r" + xx +"-T fields -e ip.len -e ip_hdr_len")
```

```
import glob 
import os 

filey = open("try.csv",'a')
filey.writelines("Lable,IPlength,DestIP")
packets = rdpcap("bruteforce.pcapng")

for xx in packets:
  all = str (os.popen(tsharkcommand).read())
  all = all.splitlines()

  for features in all:
      filey.writelines("Lable"+ "," + features + "\n")
```

how can I solve that?
and if you have any way to extract features easier than this way, please provide me.

Comment: tshark's `-r` parameter is supposed to get a filename argument, but you're attempting to give it a packet which wouldn't make sense even if it didn't raise the error.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could figure out of your code you're trying to run the `tshark` command using the `infile` option to get `ip.len` and `ip_hdr_len` out of the input file.

However, `scapy.all.rdpcap()` doesn't return a file but instead returns `packets[Packet]` object type which is not suited for your purpose.

You can instead use `xx.fields.values()` to get the `src.ip`, `dst.ip`, `ip.length` of each packet in the `pcap` file